# modify response header without using xpcom in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I am new to extension development. My requirement is to create a simple extension which modifies some response headers and adds some new headers to the http response. I was looking through some addons like redisposition and inline disposition. The former one does the same job without using xpcom and the later one uses xpcom. Also the former one has xul (gui) components too.
  Now, is it possible to modify the response if extension has no overlay (gui components).

Comment: I'm assuming that you confuse `XPCOM` (Cross Platform Component Object Model)  with `XUL` (the GUI markup language)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a GUI.

There are several ways to get your code running:

- Create a bootstrapped (restartless) add-on, just like `ReDisposition` (The GUI parts there are not required) and register from your `bootstrap.js`.
- Create an SDK add-on and register from your `main.js`.
- Create an XPCOM component and register it for `profile-after-change` (run at startup, basically) and register once the component gets loaded.
- Or have a stub overlay, that will just load a [JS code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules) and register in the module. (A little hackish for my taste, but anyway).

Anyway, in the end, you'll need to register and observe [`http-examine-response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests) and friends, no matter what method you use, or what

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for more documentation (and the [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) wiki).

Other than that, your question is too broad to tell you something less general.

Comment: @nmaler I will be using the bootstrapped addon. When I removed the gui stuff from bootstrap.js file of redisposition it didn't work.Honestly, I am still struggling to figure out how an extension is debugged. I followed all the instructions but I don't see any error in web console. Here is the modified code: http://pastebin.com/YDVz0Wtj

Comment: Errors will be logged to the Error Console (or Browser Console if you use a bleeding-edge Firefox). Please don't hide updates in comments. Either update your question, or ask a new one if the scope is radically shifted.

Comment: But to make matters short: `Exception: _ is not a function; ReDisposition@Scratchpad/1:423`. You commented out the `_` function initialization, but not the later calls to `_()`, e.g. on like 423.

Comment: @nmaler Actually the code is so long, It would have created a mess. Thanks for the help. Other than this error, is there any other error.